# Downloaded Video from Alamofire is not playing in Landscape Mode

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am downloading a video through Alamofire and when I play that video in any player compatible with swift , video is playing only in portrait mode. I need to play video in landscape mode also. Here is my code -

'
     request = Alamofire.download(videoImageUrl!, to: destination).downloadProgress
     { progress in

```
   self.isDownloading = true

        print("\(floor(progress.fractionCompleted*100))%")
        self.downloadingView.downloadPercentagaeView.text = "\(Int(floor(progress.fractionCompleted*100)))% of \(String(format: "%.1f", (Double(sizeOfVideo) * 0.000001)))MB"
        }

        .response { response in
          if let error = response.error {
            print(error)
            if self.isDownloadCancelled == false {
          if !HasfitHelper.shared.isInternetConnected {

            let internetErrorView = internetDisconnectedView.internetAlertView() as! UIView

            internetErrorView.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
            internetDisconnectedView.internetDisconectedDelegate = self
            HasfitHelper.mainWindow().rootViewController?.view.addSubview(internetErrorView)

              }
              if response.resumeData != nil {
              self.dataCache.set(response.resumeData!, forKey: videoImageUrl!)
              print(self.dataCache.value(forKey: videoImageUrl!) as Any)
              }}

          if self.isDownloadCancelled == true
          {
            self.dataCache.set(nil, forKey: videoImageUrl!)
            print(self.dataCache.value(forKey: videoImageUrl!) as Any)
            return
          }
         }
          if response.destinationURL != nil {

            print(response.destinationURL!)



            self.downloadVideoForOfflineButton.setImage(UIImage(named:"download_filled_icon"), for: .normal)
            self.isDownloaded = true
            self.offlineVideoUrl = "\(response.destinationURL!)"
            self.dataCache.set(nil, forKey: videoImageUrl!)



            self.tableView.reloadData()
            if self.isfavorite == false {
              self.rightPressed(self)
            }
            let remoteImageURL = URL(string: (self.workoutInfoDict[kAPIParam.thumbnail] as? String)!)
            Alamofire.request(remoteImageURL!).responseData { (responseImage) in
              if responseImage.error == nil {
                print(responseImage.result)
                let dict = ["post_id":self.postID,"file_url":"\(response.destinationURL!)","thumbnail":self.workoutInfoDict[kAPIParam.thumbnail]!,"post_name":self.workoutInfoDict[kAPIParam.postName]!,"thumbnailData":responseImage.data!] as [String : Any]

                var offlineDict = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "offlineDict") as! [Any]
                offlineDict.append(dict)
                UserDefaults.standard.set(offlineDict, forKey: "offlineDict")
                UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
                self.downloadingView.removeFromSuperview()
                self.isDownloading = false
}
```

'

Answer (score 0):

Please check the device orientation in your info.plist of your app.

To get a landscape video, you may need to check Landscape mode for your app.

Although I'm not sure this will solve your issue, it worth a try.

[image]

Comment: its happening because video is downloading only in portrait mode , so that content is not able to played in landscape mode in any player supported by iOS.